# how can i connect to multiple peers using GKPeerPickerController object

Tags: iphone

i have used GKPeerPickerController to connect to iPhoes via bluetooth.Now when my application launches,i am able to search the iPhones nearby but when i select any one of them,it starts connecting to that iPhone.Now when they are connected,I have dismissed picker.My problem is that how will i connect to rest of iPhones.how can i make picker to listen to any request that is coming in between the running application.

I tried to create another object of picker which will keep listening the request but it will not be shown to user untill any request comes.But i found that picker can not detect untill it is shown.Correct me if i am wrong and suggest me something regarding this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GKSession` to detect devices and connect them.
`GKPeerPickerController` just helps you connect two devices,which as jkap said!

Comment: As far as I can see its two devices as you say and then only by bluetooth unless you write your interface to set up the wifi. You can tell it choose between Wifi and BT, but it only actually helps you if you choose BT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect multiples using GKPeerPickerController. You would have to design and code your own view controller to be able to connect more than one, as PeerPickerController seems to be specifically designed to only connect two devices together.